# Naming Spring Services when accessed by different client types

Tags: java, spring

I am quite new to Spring and have a question related to Spring Service naming convention.

I have written a service, and used an annotation to define and name it.

@Service(value="CustomerService")

This service is implemented within a library that is used by a web app. Everything works fine and I can autowire my service into my client components.

Now I would also like to expose this service using http invoker. This works ok. I have define a /CustomerService http service which accesses CustomerService bean.

The issue I have is that one of my components, a client side component, that I used in my web app (CustomerDetailsValidator) can also be used in this new application.

In my CustomerDetailsValidator I have something like this:

@Autowired
@Qualifier(name="CustomerService").

But if I want to reuse my CustomerDetailsValidator and use it in my new app, this time I need to wire it to the httpservice instead.
Which means that the @Autowired and @Qualifier code is useless.

My question is what is the best practice in this case?

Should I still use @Service?
I guess I cannot use Qualifier anymore.

My feeling is that I should define everything in xml in each application context.

The web app using the library directly would just use the CustomerService bean as a singleton.
While my new client app would link the customer service id to the http service.

Is that a good approach? Do we have patterns for this?

Thanks and regards

Gilles